# Exchanging UK License for German License (but with a twist)

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, driving-license

I currently hold a UK Driving License but am living in the US, and I am looking to move to Germany. The issue I have is that the UK license card I seem to have is an older card, which does not have the last address I had when I left UK.

Can I still exchange my UK license for a German one?

Thank you

Comment: Thanks Tomas! Is my license still considered "valid" since it does not have the right address?

Comment: @Tomas By Maybe, although the OP could be liable to a fine of up to £1,000 for not telling the DVLA when their last UK address changed https://www.gov.uk/change-address-driving-licence

Comment: @Traveller I have updated my address with DVLA, and on the online version, I have right address. Just the card I have is the older one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you replace the card before the end of 2020, then you will be treated in the same way as an EU citizen in Germany, as the Brexit transition phase is still in place.  So the process is fairly simple.

When you apply to change your licence then the German authorities will contact the DVLA in the UK to validate various details about the card and yourself and then, if everything is in order, issue you with a new German driving licence in place of the UK licence.

The German authorities will not care if the address stated on the card was correct at the time when you left the UK or not.  This is a matter for the UK authorities.

You are in fact not required to replace your UK licence for a German one until the UK one expires (which is normally 10 years after issue).
So this means that any address details printed on the card could anyway be up to 10 years out of date.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense